# Difference between "inferred from" and "inferred by"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What is the difference (if any) between the following:

> This fact (A) is inferred **from** that fact (B).

and

> This fact (A) is inferred **by** that fact (B).

Any other preposition that could be used in the above sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure _inferred by_ can be used that way.  You could say _Fact A was inferred by Joe_ but I don't think a fact can infer anything.  You might say _Fact A was inferred **from** Fact B **by** Joe._

Comment: @RogerSinasohn E.g. The fact that the street is wet is inferred by the fact that it's raining. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, but it's not the street that's doing the inferring.  It is the speaker  that is inferring.  Consider this:  _The young constable asked how the detective new that the street would be wet and the detective explained, "the fact that the street is wet is inferred by the fact that it is raining."_  The **detective** inferred the street's wetness.

Comment: I will note that that is an unusual way of saying it and I doubt any native speaker would say that.

Comment: Also, if someone says _I inferred that the street was wet by looking out the window and noticing it was raining_, I believe the whole _by_ part is simply an adverbial phrase modifying _inferred_ to show how it was done.

Comment: @RicardoBiehlPasquali, no, you cannot say 'The fact that the street is wet is inferred by the fact that it's raining.' The phrase *inferred by* needs to be followed by some reference to the *person* who is doing the reasoning. What you can say is 'The fact that the street is wet is **entailed** by the fact that it's raining' or 'The fact that the street is wet is **implied** by the fact that it's raining'.

Comment: @jsw29 *Implied* has the same problem as *inferred*, just in reverse. Facts don't imply anything. Both implication and inference require intention.

Comment: "This fact (A) is inferred **from** that fact (B)." No issues. Just relax.

Comment: @JasonBassford, *imply* often takes a human (or similarly rational) being as the subject (like *infer* **always** does), but it doesn't have to: in logic one routinely says that a proposition (e.g. that it is raining) implies another proposition (e.g. that the street is wet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb *to infer* is often confounded with *to entail*. That is understandable, because they are close in meaning: they concern the same logical relationship. They are, however, not interchangeable, because their meaning is not quite the same, and because they are syntactically quite different. The second example in this question is an attempt to treat *to infer* as if it had the syntactical features of *to entail*.

To understand why this is a mistake, consider first:

B entails A.

This tells us that B, the premise, as a matter of logic leads to A, the conclusion. If that is true, it is true regardless of whether anyone has ever thought about it. But if it is true, then it is possible that somebody will, at some time, think about it. When a particular person comes to appreciate that B entails A, we can say:

So-and-so has inferred A from B.

While *to entail* is about the logical relationship itself, *to infer* is about something that takes place in the ‘head’ of a particular person. The syntax of *to infer* requires as the subject some term that stands for that person, unlike *to entail*, which takes as the subject a term for the premise.

When we want to use *to entail* in the passive voice, we say something like:

A is entailed by B

(where, as before, A is the conclusion, and B the premise). When we transform the above example involving *to infer* into the passive, we get:

A has been inferred from B, by so-and-so.

Note that the preposition *from* here introduces the premise, just like it does in the active voice, while *by* introduces the term for the person who performed the inference. The preposition *by* does not introduce the same item in the passive sentence with *to infer* as it does in the passive sentence with *to entail* because these two verbs do not take the same items as subjects when used in the active voice.

The passive voice, of course, makes it possible to entirely omit any explicit reference to the person doing the action and still use *to infer*. One can thus say:

A has been inferred from B,

A is inferred from B,

A can be inferred from B.

The last of these is interchangeable with ‘A is entailed by B’. It is when one uses *to infer* in the passive, without referring to a person, that the tendency to confuse it with *to entail* is particularly strong, which may lead one to the error of saying ‘inferred by B’. To resist this tendency, one should always remember that in the active voice the subject of that verb stands for the person performing the action. If one keeps that in mind, then the right prepositions to use with *to infer* in the passive will fall into their places: *from* for the premise, *by* for the person, if mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

"Inferred by" is a bit strange, but could be used to mean the person who inferred something (in a passive sentence). That is:

> He inferred that something was wrong.
>
> It was inferred that something was wrong by him.

These two sentences mean the same thing, just in an active or passive voice. The second sentence is grammatically correct, but very unnatural and awkward.

In terms of the meaning you are aiming for in the sentence, that we can make a logical conclusion based on a fact, we would prefer the preposition "from". You can think of it as information coming *to* you *from* the other fact. For example,

> I inferred he was angry from his sour expression.