# Infer to mean imply?

Tags: differences, synonyms

I am watching [this video](https://youtu.be/CNPuKv_pNks?t=225), and at 3:45 Justice Scalia says he gets upset when he hear "infer" used to mean "imply"

1. Is there any real world example of "infer" used to mean "imply"?
2. Why "infer" cannot be used to mean "imply"?
3. What's the correct usage of "infer"?

Comment: Do you know whether you're coming or going?

Comment: @HotLicks I think yours is a joke but I don't understand it

Comment: The linked question on infer vs reply covers it all, but "infer" has another, old meaning, "to point out, indicate", which can be mistaken for "imply" as in Shakespeare: "this poor show doth better: this doth infer the zeal I had to see him." https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imply

Comment: Can someone explain to me the joke by @HotLicks? I am a foreigner

Comment: @raffaem We are asked countless questions which could have been answered with the use of [Google](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=imply) or a dictionary. If a chap is utterly baffled and confused he may say he *doesn't know whether he's coming or going*. Perhaps Hot Licks [got out of bed the wrong side](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-out-of-bed-on-the-wrong-side) this morning :-)

Comment: Related: [Difference between “inferred from” and “inferred by”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460475).

Answer (score 3):

Using *infer* rather than *imply* is quite a common mistake. A dictionary will tell you that imply means 'suggest' or 'indicate', while infer means 'deduce'.

The difference is explained in the 1989 film of Tom Sharpe's *Wilt*.

Police Inspector Flint has read Wilt’s lecture notes in which he discusses the low level of intelligence of the average policeman.

> *Police Inspector:* "You're inferring that we're all thick."
>
> *Wilt:* "No, I'm **implying** that you're all thick. You're **inferring** from what I've written that I think you're all thick."

If the cream's gone and the cat's licking its lips one may infer it has had the cream.

Comment: This is one difference. The other is that *infer* requires as its subject a term for a human or human-like being: there has to be **somebody** who does the inferring. *Imply* can take such a subject, but it can also be said that some statement (sentence, proposition, etc.) implies something.